# Is there a print function for PHP that produces a valid PHP expression?

Tags: php

I'm after a way of getting PHP to print an arbitrary array out in a form that I can include into my (test) code as an assignment.

print_r produces e.g:

```
Array
(
[0] => qsr-part:1285
[1] => qsr-part:1286
)
```

which is almost, but not quite, valid.

I need e.g:

```
array('qsr-part:1285', 'qsr-part:1286')
```

Answer (score 5):

[`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) does exactly this: it exports a value into its PHP representation as a string.

Note that arrays are always exported as associated key-value pairs, so you'll get something like this, but it shouldn't matter either way:

```
array (
  0 => 'qsr-part:1285',
  1 => 'qsr-part:1286',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either an array or object and try `json_encode` on one side and `json_decode` on the other.